# SQL Server TLS 1.2 communication really encrypted?

Tags: c#, sql-server, ssl, encryption, tls1.2

I'm writing a VB6 application which connects with SQL Server. To secure the connection with the database I'm using MSOLEDBSQL as provider which supports TLS 1.2. I also enabled TLS 1.2 in my machine. I verified the connection status using sys. dm_exec_connections and SQL server displays all the connections are encrypted. To double confirm I tried to use the echomirage to check the traffic and the results are surprising. The data is not encrypted and I can read all the data flow as shown in the below image. My question is

1. This communication is really encrypted. If not why I'm seeing different status in SQL server
2. I read somewhere that TCP is binary protocol. If so, why I'm seeing plain text even if this communication is not encrypted?

[image]

Comment: What does your connection string look like? Does it contain `TrustServerCertificate=true;Encrypt=true;`?

Comment: Are you sure that EchoMirage isn't showing the non-HTTPS version of the traffic?  These network protocol apps can decrypt secure traffic by acting as a proxy or utilising the local certificat keys used for the encryption.

Comment: Are you sure you're looking at the correct capture? SQL Server's protocol doesn't use XML. Maybe you tried to post an XML string, or the database returns an XML result, but TDS, the protocol, isn't XML-based. `I read somewhere that TCP is binary protocol.` this isn't a `read somewhere`. All network protocols are binary. All transfer bytes. Some of them represent text, some not.

Comment: If you really want to check anything use SSMS, not the paleolithic VB6. It's far more likely that you're seeing problems in your code or the way you use ADO than actual problems with SQL Server. PS: the screenshot actually shows you that the content is binary, with a translation to text on the right

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos yes it is a DB data and a binary one.

Comment: @Martin ok, so is possible for a middle man to use this tool and see the traffic? just curious.

Comment: @Jay only if *you* give them *your* trusted certificates. Same way Fiddler decrypts HTTPS data. This has nothing to do with SQL Server.  Any proxy can pose as a server, intercept your browser's data, decrypt it and inspect it. During the SSL connection though, the client and server verify each other through their certificates. A MiTM proxy won't have a valid certificate and the browser will block the connection and warn you with a big red screen. It's the same with SQL Server - to prevent MITM attacks you need TLS *and* verification

Comment: @Jay to prevent MITM attacks with SQL Server you should **not** use `TrustServerCertificate=true;`. This disables validation. If you want to use a self-signed certificate for testing you'll have to add it to the machine's trusted certificates, *not* disable validation. [Using Encryption Without Validation in SQL Server Native Client](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/native-client/features/using-encryption-without-validation?view=sql-server-ver15) explains. what happens when you don't use validation, with a big red warning against it

Comment: @Llama `TrustServerCertificate=true;` would allow interception by disabling validation.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Sorry, I misread the documentation. You're right.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Thanks a lot. You have a great knowledge.

Answer (score 3):

This isn't a TDS issue (the protocol used by SQL Server). The same thing happens with your browser when you use a debugging proxy like Fiddler *and* trust the proxy's certificate, or configure it to use a trusted certificate. Most likely, you trusted EchoMirage's certificate during setup or through its Settings and forgot about it.

SSL/TLS protect agains [Man-In-The-Middle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Man-in-the-middle_attack) attacks by *verifying* the other party through certificates. Encryption isn't enough. Without verification a proxy between client and server could pose as the other party, set up encrypted communications with each side, decrypt the packets it receives, inspect them and then encrypt them again using the other side's keys and send them along. Without verification neither client nor server would know someone intercepted the connections.

With SSL/TLS, a connection is established only if both parties trust each other's certificates. Both sides verify the certificates by checking either whether the certificate is explicitly trusted, or if it was issued by a Certificate Authority trusted by the application. If validation fails, the connection fails as well.

Fiddler, WireShark and other similar tools decrypt traffic by acting like a proxy and establishing communications on either side using *their* certificate. With certificate validation enabled though, the browser (or the SQL Server client) would reject the connection. If you try to connect to a web site through HTTPS while Fiddler is in use you'd get a red warning page saying that the connection isn't safe.

To allow such connections someone would have to go and *explicitly* trust the tool's certificate. All tools can do this through their settings, but all OSs require privilege elevation and user confirmation before they add the certificate to their trusted list.

By default, drivers and network libraries perform validation. To allow WireShark to intercept the SQL Server connection you'd have to either explicitly disable validation with `TrustServerCertificate=true;`, or trust the tool's certificate, which is probably something you already did and forgotten about it.

The page [Using Encryption Without Validation in SQL Server Native Client](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/native-client/features/using-encryption-without-validation?view=sql-server-ver15) in the docs explains what happens when you don't use validation, and warns against it.

If you use `Encrypt=true` and leave `TrustServerCertificate` to its default, `false`, WireShark or EchoMirage won't be able to intercept, much less decrypt the traffic. In this case :

> Encryption occurs only if there is a verifiable server certificate, otherwise the connection attempt fails.

Comment: Wireshark doesn't decrypt by acting like a proxy, wireshark decrypts by giving it the keys to the TLS session. The most common way this is done is by launching your favorite browser from, say, a shell with the environment variable SSLKEYLOGFILE set to a file. The browser (and other compliant TLS clients) will then dump master keys, nonces, and whatever else is needed to decrypt the TLS sessions. You can tell Wireshark to look to this file to attempt TLS decryption. If you haven't done this and see plaintext in wireshark then connection is not using TLS.

Answer (score 1):

This is a TDS issue (the protocol used by SQL Server), and is not caused by WireShark in any way.

TLS encryption is only used during the **login process** to ensure that the credentials are not passed unencrypted over the network.

After that, the remaining bulk-transfer of queries and result sets are **not** encrypted on the wire.

In order to enable encryption for data (and not just for the login process), you need to use the [`Use Encryption for Data`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/native-client/applications/using-connection-string-keywords-with-sql-server-native-client?view=sql-server-ver16) connection string keyword in your connection string:

```
Use Encryption for Data=true
```

- `Use Encryption for Data`
- `SSPROP_INIT_ENCRYPT`
- *"Specifies whether data should be encrypted before sending it over the network. Possible values are "true" and "false". The default value is "false"."*

Be aware: If you `enable encryption for data`, and the server doesn't have a valid certificate (i.e. the default), then you will get an error when connecting. The client will detect the server presented an invalid certificate, and stop the connection. In order to make your system reliable, you need to include `Trust Server Certificate=true` in your connection string:

```
Use Encryption for Data=true;Trust Server Certificate=true
```

A better alternative is to turn on the option on the **server** that forces encryption for data, and do **not** specify `Use Encryption for Data` or `Trust Server Certificate` in your connection string.

When it is the **server** that requires the encryption, the client will not care about the certificate presented by the server (excluding MSOLEDBSQL19, which is broken by default, and you will need to specify `Trust Server Certificate=true` even when it was the server who wanted the encryption in the first place.